# Can't remove docker images with dependent children

Tags: docker, dependencies

I'm trying to remove an image but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ docker rmi -f 
9ef344b4632a73d70e081a4b7345ba3ff6a333fcfb7fed0c9118881f3f582677
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 9ef344b4632a 
(cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
```

When I look for the dependent images, it generates no output:

```
$ for i in $(docker images -a --quiet); do
> docker inspect $i | jq -r '.[].RootFS' | grep sha256:9ef344b4632a
> done
```

How can I find the dependent image it's complaining about?

Answer (score 4):

The parent image ID is stored in a different field. Here's an easy way to search for that:

```
search_id='9ef344b4632a'
for i in $(docker image ls -aq); do
  docker image inspect --format '{{.Parent}}' $i | grep -q "$search_id" && echo $i
done
```